# Embed Analytics in Lightning Page with MULTIPLE Filters

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

I have an Analytics dashboard embedded on an Account record page. I need to filter it to only include data from the current Account AND Accounts to which this Account is the Parent.

I'm using the following in the 'Filter' Field in the Lightning page editor:

```
'datasets':{
    'my_dataset':[
        {
            'fields':['AccountId.Name'], 
            'filter':{'operator': 'matches', 'values':['$Name']}
        },
        {
            'fields':['AccountId.ParentId.Name'], 
            'filter':{'operator': 'matches', 'values':['$Name']}
        }
    ]
}
```

However this only ever seems to take the first filter into place. It is possible to include multiple filters?

Comment: Does your dashboard Step have its **Selection Type** set to Multiple to allow for multiple values to be used when filtering? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_dashboard_step_properties_flex.htm